# How to get the name of the view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I am using the following code to get the name of the view controller so far navigated,

```
NSMutableArray *navigationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
NSLog(@"%@",navigationArray);
```

but i am using this method in storyboard this is not working can any one help to fix this

Comment: you were try to fetch current view controller name

Comment: That isn't the name of the view controller, that's an array of view controller instances.

Comment: yes how to use this code in storyboard, can i use @ trojanFoe

Comment: May be you meant a view controller's `title`?

Comment: which _name_ are you asking about? the storyboard id? the class name? the xib name (if different)?

Comment: Hey @Arun explain your scenario where you need class name. It helps to suggest best solution and possible ways to obtain viewcontroller

Comment: @Avinash Jadav i have navigated 4 screen in the fourth screen i need to get the name all the view controllers on a array.this is the scenario

Comment: And for what purpose you are using those view controller instances? You can get instance of any view controller on storyboard with identifier...

Answer (score 3):

use [NSStringFromClass()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIIABFJ). It returns the name of a class as a `string`.

if you want to fetch some view controller name , do like

```
   NSString *viewName = NSStringFromClass([yourviewControllerName class]);
```

if you want to fetch current view controller , do like

```
NSString *viewName = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
```

**fetch previous Viewcontrollers**

You can use the `UINavigationController`'s `viewControllers` property:

> @property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers

```
NSArray * allViewController = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
```

**another choice**

get count of viewcontrollers available in navigation use like

```
NSInteger totalCount = self.navigationController.viewControllers.count;
```

**Updated**

```
UIViewController *allViewController = self.navigationController.viewControllers[totalCount - 2];
Class previousVCClass = [allViewController class];
NSString *className = NSStringFromClass(previousVCClass);
```

Comment: i need to get the name of all the view controller i have navigated.,

Comment: it is returning NULL, the code i have posted works in xib bur in storyboard i was unable to get the result.

Comment: are your embeded your viewcontrollers in navigation stack

Comment: @Arun Then you are probably not using Navigation Controller at all. You are probably presenting it modally

Comment: @Anbu yes i implemented . your first and second one is working i am getting the current controller name , but i need the entire name of the view controller so far i have navigated.

Comment: @Arun -- the third one is returned the array , nsnoob elobrated the array I am not elobrated , this is the difference

Comment: @Arun -- check the updated answer, bro for example purpose

Comment: @NSNoob i have embedded in navigation Controller.

Comment: That's fine but when you drag segue, what type of segue do you select? Push? or present modally?

Comment: @Nob UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    
    thirdCtrl *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"thirdResId"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];       doing it is code

Comment: @Arun -- **presentViewController** does not embed with `Navigation controller`, if we need, we need to implement the navigation controller manually, thats the reason you are not get the all view controlers name

Comment: You will have to do `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES]`. Also your naming convention is troublesome.

Comment: simple , just change this `[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];` to `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];`, thats all bro

Comment: @Arun -- if  our answer is useful give the upvote and tickmark for anyone it is useful for future , and happy day bro

Comment: @anbu yes it is a fine piece of answer. tank u

Answer (score 2):

You will have to iterate on navigation stack and use Anbu's solution to retrieve their class name:

```
NSMutableArray* viewControllersNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(UIViewController *vc in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
{
    NSString *vcName = NSStringFromClass([vc class]);
    [viewControllersNames addObject:vcName];

}
```

In the property [`self.navigationController.viewControllers`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/viewControllers), all your viewcontrollers which haven't been popped yet are stored. Here we are iterating over them and adding their class names in an array. Your first `ViewController` will be at `0` index of array and your last one (The View controller which is currently presenting) will be at `count-1` index.

This solution will work only if you are presenting your viewControllers via navigation controller. If you are using modal presentation, it won't work. As your post gives the impression that you're using Navigation Controller, and you say that you are doing that, so solution is also for Nav controller approach.

Comment: the shortest and right answer. I support.  @Arun,  use it.   If you want the title of view controller, as @ Andrey Gordeev mentioned in comments under your question, then the code will be something like `NSString *vcTitle = vc.title;   [viewControllerNames addObject:vcTitle];  `

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to resolve issue
On Storyboard select each view controller and go to Class inspector. Then set storyboard identifier unique to each view controller.
You can access instance of any view controller.

```
id controller =  [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ControllerIdentifier"];
```

Another way

```
  NSMutableArray *navigationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
  id  controller1 = [navigationArray objectAtIndex: 0];
  id  controller1 = [navigationArray objectAtIndex: 1];
  ....
```

Comment: And this code will crash let's say if there is only one ViewController the array and index goes out of bound. Plus accessing the VC's isn't his question.

Comment: Hey @NSNoob I have just suggested possible way. You can construct your logic according your requirement.